# Does all OpenCV functions throw exceptions?

Tags: c++, opencv

[OpenCV throws exceptions when hitting critical errors](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/intro.html#error-handling), however, in the documentation it is rarely (dare I say never) mentioned whether a particular function throws. See for instance the [documentation on the watershed algorithm](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga3267243e4d3f95165d55a618c65ac6e1)

I would like to catch errors close to where they occur and, for instance, wrap the call to watershed in a try-catch. But the documentation does not state whether the function throws, so wrapping it in try-catch may be a false security.

Can I assume that all OpenCV functions throws exceptions?

Comment: Pretty much anything using memory might throw `std::bad_alloc`. Exceptions are not Pokemon, there's no need to catch 'm all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I assume that all OpenCV functions throws exceptions?

For the most part, yes. Many OpenCV methods will most likely perform a [`CV_ASSERT`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core_c.h#L2751) which will call [`cvError`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/system.cpp#L802). In turn, `cv::error` will log, and throw exception.

> But the documentation does not state whether the function throws, so wrapping it in try-catch may be a false security.

My rule-of-thumb is that if the method returns `void`, and the method is manipulative and/or acts on a resource, then it's wise to wrap in a try-catch. When in doubt, I'll evaluate the source code of the method to see what the assertions are checking for.